# Closing suggested edit rejection dialog doesn't bring back review buttons

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When I click the Reject button when reviewing a suggested edit on Stack Overflow, it opens a dialog box. If I click the close button, the dialog disappears, but Approve, Reject, Improve, and Skip buttons don't come back. There is still just a disabled button that says "Rejecting...".

[image]

There is an error in the JavaScript console too:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of null full.en.js?v=4e67ead1b5c6:44
d full.en.js?v=4e67ead1b5c6:44
h full.en.js?v=4e67ead1b5c6:44
StackExchange.init.a stub.en.js?v=e3d47b73fa12:5
(anonymous function) stub.en.js?v=e3d47b73fa12:6
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i jquery.min.js:3
f.event.trigger jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:3
e.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.each jquery.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.trigger jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) review.en.js?v=f45b4ec094ea:64
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i jquery.min.js:3
```

I'm running Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on Mac OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: It happens if you click the [X] itself or press ESC, clicking anywhere outside the dialog will close it properly and the buttons show just fine.